# MVVM WPF Scientific application with dialogs

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, logic, prism

I'm moving existing C++/CLI application to C#/WPF.  When initial application was written no design was done whatsoever.  Application has an ability to load one or more image files (only one image is visible at a time), also there is an option to connect to a microscope and see and save images in real time (images from microscope show at the same image box as the loaded ones).  Then, there are a lot of dialogs with different settings.  There are buttons on the main view to make different kind of calculations based on currently loaded image files and selected settings.

There is a button to send images loaded to another window which has more functionality - makes a movie from loaded files, calculates statistics etc.

I'm fairly new to C#/WPF world, but want to make a nice design.  I did some research and it looks like MVVM is the pattern that is mostly used in WPF. Now I'm reading about PRISM. I more or less understand what's going on with MVVM, but cannot apply its logic to my situation yet.  May be I should stick to MVC?-but there are not a lot of resorces on how to use it with WPF... I found examples on where to put dialogs, but don't know where to put my calculations... looks like they don't belong to either of M/MV/V. Also, I cannot understand if I can have only one Model associated with many ViewModels.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is common misunderstanding.

MVVM is a *pattern* just like MVC. There is various frameworks that help you with MVVM. MVVMLight, Caliburn is some of the examples. I think you need to learn what MVVM is and then look for different implementations. Personally I wrote my own base View Model class and that's all to MVVM

PRISM is a framework and actually it has almost nothing to do with MVVM. It does provide `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation but that's about it.

PRISM is a big framework, it takes time to learn it. It is not something you can start using tonight. However, it is "a la cart" which means you don't have to use everything it provides and can use only what you need.

The more I learn the more I realize that PRISM solves pretty much all the problems you will have while developing big business application with heavy UI. For me, time invested in learning definitely paid back.

It provides regions, modularity, messaging, IoC and other stuff that needed when you build big application. MVVM looks tiny and easy after you see bigger picture..

Comment: Thank you. I probably didn't word my question correctly. I understand that MVVM is a pattern, I just wasn't sure that this is a pattern that I should use. I'm very familiar with MVC and C++ and not MVVM, C#, WPF.  I started using Caliburn.Micro instead of PRISM - just for a quick start. And the question I had was about where I should put my calculations, because I read somewhere that application logic doesn't belong to Model or ViewModel...